# How to change termios configuration, so that getc() immediately returns when user presses <tab> key?

Tags: c, terminal, termios

I want to implement auto-completion feature for my CLI application. The default behavior of getc() is returning only when the following list of characters are entered: NEW_LINE or EOF. I want to add TAB to this list so that I can trigger my auto-completion algorithm.

Is there a way to do it, for instance, using termios? The editline library (http://www.thrysoee.dk/editline/) can do it but I could not figure how it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling of terminal IO takes about 40 pages in the second edition of "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment"...  Rapidly, you can set the eol and eol2 (termios.c_cc[EOL] and termios.c_cc[EOL2]) characters to have additional characters behaving like \n.

You can even try this with stty

```
$ cat -
abc\tdef
abc\tdef
^d
$stty eol ^i
abc\tabc\tdef
def
^d
```

Example of how to do it in a program (in practice, don't forget error handling and restoring the original state at end, when suspended, when signaled, and so on... that's why using a packaged library to do it is better, there are a lot of details to get right for a robust application).

```
struct termios term;
tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term);
term.c_cc[EOL] = '\t';
tcsetattr(STDION_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &term);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach, which doesn't require `tcsetattr()` or `tcgetattr()` at all, is to use `cbreak()` to put the terminal into "cbreak" mode, which does not buffering or processing of control characters, and then to use `nocbreak()` when you're done to reset it.

The man page for `cbreak` documents various related functions, including `raw()` and `noecho()` that you can use to control the terminal without having to fully understand termios.

If you want finer control, you'll need to use termios directly. I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.nelhage.com/2009/12/a-brief-introduction-to-termios/) a little while ago that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using [gnu readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) isntead of killing yourself with getc()... ;)